# Angular 5 document.querySelector('ClassName').innerHTML does not contain the css inlined

Tags: javascript, css, angular, html, pdf

I'm trying to create a very useful feature to export any div as the pdf file.
I'm using Canvas to generate a screenshot of the page. and write it to a pdf file using jsPDF library. 
But the problem is because of Angular ViewEncapsultion, the CSS is not included. when I trying to access div's HTML with .innerHTML.
There is any way to bypass that?
If someone has an experience of on doing something similar.

Thanks (:

Comment: Can you show some code and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can change `encapsulation` by add `ViewEncapsulation.None`

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['...'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None   // disable encapsulation mode
})
```